# Django - no module named app

Tags: django, apache

I have been trying to get an application written in django working - but it is not working at all. I have been working on for some time too - and it is working on dev-server perfectly. But I am unable to put in the production env (apahce).

My project name is apstat and the app name is basic.

I try to access it as following

> Blockquote 
>   http://hostname/apstat

But it shows the following error:

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

ProcessId:      6002
Interpreter:    'domU-12-31-39-06-DD-F4.compute-1.internal'

ServerName:     'domU-12-31-39-06-DD-F4.compute-1.internal'
DocumentRoot:   '/home/ubuntu/server/'

URI:            '/apstat/'
Location:       '/apstat'
Directory:      None
Filename:       '/home/ubuntu/server/apstat/'
PathInfo:       ''

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'django.core.handlers.modpython'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
    result = object(arg)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 228, in handler
    return ModPythonHandler()(req)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/modpython.py", line 201, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 134, in get_response
    return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, exc_info)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 154, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/views/debug.py", line 40, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/views/debug.py", line 114, in get_traceback_html
    return t.render(c)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/__init__.py", line 178, in render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/__init__.py", line 779, in render
    bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/debug.py", line 81, in render_node
    raise wrapped

TemplateSyntaxError: Caught an exception while rendering: No module named basic

Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/debug.py", line 71, in render_node
    result = node.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/debug.py", line 87, in render
    output = force_unicode(self.filter_expression.resolve(context))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/__init__.py", line 572, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 687, in date
    return format(value, arg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 269, in format
    return df.format(format_string)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
    pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 175, in r
    return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 30, in format
    pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
    s = unicode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/functional.py", line 201, in __unicode_cast
    return self.__func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 62, in ugettext
    return real_ugettext(message)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 286, in ugettext
    return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 276, in do_translate
    _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 194, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 180, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named basic
```

My settings.py is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'apstat.basic',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

If I remove the apstat.basic, it goes through, but that is not a solution. Is it something I am doing in apache?

My apache - settings are -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/server/
        <Directory />
                Options None
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/server/apstat>
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Location "/apstat">
                SetHandler python-program
                PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
                SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE apstat.settings
                PythonOption django.root /home/ubuntu/server/
                PythonDebug On
                PythonPath "['/home/ubuntu/server/'] + sys.path"
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have now sat for more than a day on this. If someone can help me out, it would be very nice.

Comment: Found the issue. Inside __init__.py, I was doing some initializations. In dev server it worked, but in apache, some permissions issues caused it to fail. Django eats the errors, so it is non-obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does your basic have `__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes. Actually that was the problem. It had init.py which initializes the log etc. There was some problem with methinks permissions, which caused it to error out. So, when I tested with dev server, it worked fine, but inside apache it failed. Django eats the actual error log ;-(

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that the project is in your `PYTHONPATH`. Maybe try to output the `sys.path` variable at the top of your settings file:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If this doesn't work with `mod_python` try to write it to a file:

```
import sys
file('/tmp/mysyspath.txt', 'w').write(repr(sys.path))
```

But even if that will work, here is a short warning:
It's discouraged in the django community to use `mod_python`. It's no longer maintained by its creators and was never the best solution to deploy your django project. Please try `mod_wsgi` if its available for you on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the project directory is added to `sys.path` and then the app name is used directly in `INSTALLED_APPS` and in imports in other apps. Give this a try.